# How can I add an external link to a form in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am creating a form in CRM 2011 that asks a user to accept a Terms of Service agreement, and I would like to place a external link to that document within the form.

I have read about creating a navigation link along the left hand side of the form, but I believe it would be more legible to the user to display the link adjacent to the "Accept Agreement" field in the form. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an HTML Web Resource.
Create an html document (for example term.htm) with inside the link, (you can customize the aspect with `CSS`)

```xml
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq" target="_blank">Stack Overflow FAQ</a>
```

Now create a Web Resource inside CRM containing the html code and add to the form.

After the Web Resource is added to the form, inside the properties you can change the formatting style (for example to occupy 1 row and 1 column without scrolling and no border)

In this way you have one link inside the form using supported customizations.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two ways of doing this:

1. Add a field to contain the hyperlink (if create a hyperlink field) it will behave correctly. Then just set the value using JavaScript to be the correct URL. However this means saving it to the database and if the URL ever changes then you have to update all those records.
2. Add a very small html web resource with the URL in and stick that on the form.